# NSString and Pointer

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsstring

The following snippet prints the value 10,

```
    int x = 10;
    int *y = &x;
    NSLog(@"Value pointed by y = %d",*y);
```

But incase of NSString pointer as below, why are we not prefixing the variable name with * to retrieve the value it points to.

```
    NSString *country = @"USA";
    NSLog(@"Value pointed by country: %@",country);
```

Let me know if I am missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Because in the second case you're using `%@`, which means "Invoke `description` using the supplied pointer and print the NSString you get back from that call."

Answer (score 3):

You can think about this as of a purely syntactic convention - a way of keeping Objective-C a pure superset of the C language. The way the Objective-C designers decided to represent objects is with C pointers: all variables of object type, including `NSString`, must be declared as a pointer. In fact, it is an error to define a variable of an object type without an asterisk:

```
NSString country; // <<== ERROR: this will not compile
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is then is used as a variable?

Comment: @unobatbayar in the same way any other variable is used, plus a special syntax Objective-C provides for invoking methods.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are always addressed by using pointers. You can not dereference them. Therefore is is not necessary and would be wrong to dereference an object pointer.

Comment: Addition: It is technical possible to derefer object pointers, but useless.